# Laravel. Сортировка записей одной таблицы, по значениям из связанной таблицы

Tags: php, laravel

Есть таблица `report_rows`, у которой есть колонка `production_order_product_instance_id`, которая подвязывает таблицу `production_order_product_instances`, и в этой таблице есть колонка `instance_id`, которая подвязывает к себе таблицу `product_instances`, в которой есть колонка `serial_number (varchar)`

Вопрос заключается в том, как мне отсортировать колонки таблицы `report_rows` по значению таблицы `product_instances`

Вот такой подход не работает.

```
ReportRow::query()
    ->when(!empty($search['sort_by'] ?? null), function (Builder $query) use ($search) {
         switch ($search['sort_by']) {
              case 'serial_number':
                  $query->whereHas('instance.productInstance', function (Builder $query) use ($search) {
                     $query->orderBy('serial_number', $search['sort_direction'] ?? 'desc');
                  });
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });
```

Фильтровать коллекцию не хочется, хочу сделать в запросе.
Есть у кого варианты?

UPD Получилось сделать через join-ы таблиц, и ордер бай по полю. Но хотелось бы отработать вариант с whereHas, чтоб везде было стандартизировано

Comment: Ну так надо включить таблицу с данными для сортировки в источник данных запроса...

Comment: @Akina через джоины работает. Но хотелось бы отработать вариант с whereHas

Comment: Будь это условие отбора - можно было бы потрахаться с коррелированным подзапросом. Но в ORDER BY - не стреляет.

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение

```
 $query
  ->join('production_order_product_instances', 'production_order_product_instance_id', '=', 'production_order_product_instances.uuid')
  ->join('product_instances', 'product_instance_id', '=', 'product_instances.uuid')
  ->orderBy('serial_number', $search['sort_direction'] ?? 'desc');
```